# Load image from NAS path to an HTML document to generate PDF in c# asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, image, pdf, ihttphandler

We are using `HTTPHandler` to show images in our ASP.NET application, it works perfect, but we encounter issues when calling the images when generating PDF's.

Because while generating PDF from HTML, the absolute image path to be given, it doesn't take `httphandler` generated image. We changing the image `src` path to point to `httphandler` like this path `http://localhost/MyHttpHandler.ashx?ID=100"`.

But `httphandler` not at all get called. PDF got created without the image, because image is not present actually in the web server. It is present outside the application hosted folder. Please advise us to overcome this challenge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to give local path of the storage when you generate pdf, for example: file://\\yournas\yournasfolder\image.jpg

Comment: We want to use NAS path only, it's the requirement. Please help us..

Comment: Giving local path without http will the image fetched. Please explain..

Comment: you can try to give a local path (file://...), or http if your localhost working on local machine